# Getting Photos Off of OneDrive

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I had been saving my photos to OneDrive. Now that there are so many I want to save them back to my PC but it keeps putting them in OneDrive and says the PC Pictures in Library is no longer available. When I go to make another folder for Pictures it tells me there's already a folder with that name.

All I want to do is take the photos from OneDrive and put them on my PC in a folder in the Pictures Library.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Your local Picture library is at:

```
c:\Users\<yourusername>\Pictures
```

Make sure that this isn't assigned to sync to OneDrive and make sure that you are actually copying to that location (try manually entering the full path in a Windows Explorer location bar).

You may have inadvertently assigned that location to sync with OneDrive. If you have, you can always create a new folder, maybe call it "Pics" in `c:\Users\<yourusername>\` Copy to there and also add it to the Library that is also called `Pictures`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows 8 allows you to automatically upload and sync your photos with OneDrive. I don't know for certain, but it probably merges your local Pictures folder with the OneDrive folder if that's enabled.

Go into Settings, find the OneDrive settings and disable syncing for pictures. Try copying them after syncing is disabled.